# Add spacing between points in HighChart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to add more spacing between points with similar values so they don't look that cluttered as in the photo? I am using HighCharts. I changed the steps of the Y axis but it looks the same because values have 1-5% difference.

[image]

```
Highcharts.chart('id', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: chartName
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: chartCategories
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} %'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                format: '{y} %'
            },
            enableMouseTracking: true
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}; padding:0"> {series.name}: ' + '<b>{point.y} %</b></span>',
        useHTML: true
    },
    series: chartSeries
});
```

});

Comment: No, because "more space" means "another value" in this view. Does HighCharts have a zoom extension to get a closer look for a better temporarily viewing by user interaction? This is not a solution, but probably a kind of workaround for a better detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tickPositioner` function and maximize space occupied by series:

```
yAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function(){
        const positions = [],
            step = (this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 5;
        
        for (var i = this.dataMin; i <= this.dataMax; i += step) {
            positions.push(i);
        }
        
        return positions;
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pe7qy816/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner